# Question about simple perceptron code

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I'm reading through Sebastian Raschka's Python Machine Learning, and I see something confusing that is not explained in the text.

In the code on this page:
https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book/blob/master/code/ch02/ch02.ipynb

### Implementing a perceptron learning algorithm in Python

In the training process, in addition to updating weights, I see this happening:

```
 self.w_[0] += update
```

Then later on, during "prediction," when weights are applied to input, I see `self.w_[0]` being used:

```
def net_input(self, X):
    """Calculate net input"""
    return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]
```

It looks like this is a bias being added into the perceptron, but the book says that `net_input` is simply calcuating "weights transpose dot x" and mentions nothing about this `+ self.w_[0]` part...

Can anyone take a look at the linked code and make sense of what's going on with the `self.w_[0]` part? Or has anyone else got this book that might explain why that's there?

Comment: It's probably treating the data as points in affine space, not vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the book's English explanation is probably a simplification (or maybe it has adopted the standard convention of adding an extra dimension to x that holds a constant value $1$).  It seems like most likely you've already given the explanation; it's adding the bias value.